# Template matching for an element under a parent so that nothing happens in the output

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have to match an element a whose parent element name is b. However it doesnt work with the code I tried

I tried the below code as that whenever the input is matched, there should not be anything done to the output

```
   <xsl:template match="*[../b][a]" mode="string">

</xsl:template>
```

I expect the template match on an xml where the current node is a, whose parent element is b

Comment: To match an element whose parent element name is `b`, use `match="b/*"`. If you cannot make it work, post a reproducible example - see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> current node is a, whose parent element is b

This what exactly describes the following pattern:

```
match="b/a"
```